# Matlab, Comma-separated string to Cell when it has blank e.g. 1,2,3,[blank],[blank]

Tags: matlab, csv, delimiter, strsplit

In Matlab,

```
1. strsplit('a,b,c,', ',')
2. strsplit('a,b,c,,,', ',')
```

both results of 1 and 2 are same,

```
{{'a'}, {'b'}, {'c'}, {0×0 char}}
```

However I want to take

```
{{'a'}, {'b'}, {'c'}, {0×0 char}, {0×0 char}, {0×0 char}}
```

from a string

```
'a,b,c,,,'.
```

I tried 'CollapseDelimiters' option in strsplit function.
But It does not work for tails.

Comment: `strsplit('a,b,c,,,', ',','CollapseDelimiters',0)` is giving the correct output on my machine... ?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness ah. You're right. The data has wrong format. Appreciated for your kind answer to silly question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As UnbearableLighness suggested, CollapseDelimiters works but you could also use split

```
>> strsplit('a,b,c,,,', ',','CollapseDelimiters',false)

ans =

  1×6 cell array

    {'a'}    {'b'}    {'c'}    {0×0 char}    {0×0 char}    {0×0 char}


>> split('a,b,c,,,', ',')'

ans =

  1×6 cell array

    {'a'}    {'b'}    {'c'}    {0×0 char}    {0×0 char}    {0×0 char}
```

I would suggest split because of the performance boost

```
function profFunc

    n = 1e5;

    tic
    for i = 1:n
        x = strsplit('a,b,c,,,', ',','CollapseDelimiters',false);
    end
    toc

    tic
    for i = 1:n
        x = split('a,b,c,,,', ',');
    end
    toc
end

>> profFunc
Elapsed time is 31.044903 seconds.
Elapsed time is 1.761662 seconds.
```